# When users are contributing a duplicate record is created in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-contacts

A member when contributing again is not linking to the member but creating a new profile even if name is different? can we have only unique email for member contribution?

Comment: Please can you give us an example. i.e. "Person A makes a contribution with email address XYZ, Person B..."

Comment: Person A makes a contribution of Rs.1000 and uses abc@mail.com. Person A again makes a contribution of Rs.500 for another event and uses same Email ID. How to merge the two Persons without creating different profile in CiviCRM 4.6.10. Sorry I am new to civicrm

Answer (score 3):

This should be able to be controlled via your Matching Rules.

I would suggest you read up about them and look at your DeDupe/Matching rules at civicrm/contact/deduperules?reset=1

Comment: Hi , I am new to Civicrm and i am unaware where to set this links could you please guide me : Below is the scenario -   
 
Person A makes a contribution of Rs.1000 and uses abc@mail.com. Person A again makes a contribution of Rs.500 for another event and uses same Email ID. How to merge the two Persons without creating different profile in CiviCRM 4.6.10. Sorry I am new to civicrm

Comment: It is all explained in this chapter: https://book.civicrm.org/user/current/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/